# Spark - Snappy library not available

Tags: hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, snappy

I trying to save a Mllib model.

Code that I have run in Spark:

```
model = RandomForest.trainClassifier(train_data, 
                                 numClasses=2, categoricalFeaturesInfo=categoricalFeaturesInfo,
                                 numTrees=numTrees, featureSubsetStrategy="auto",
                                 impurity=impurity, maxDepth=maxDepth, maxBins=maxBins)

model.save(sc, "file:///path/to/models/model_name")
```

The error message was:

```
native snappy library not available: 
this version of libhadoop was built without snappy support
```

#### Spark's information

Spark version:

1.6.1

Code to start Spark:

```
pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0 --master "local[8]" --driver-memory 6G --executor-memory 6G --jars /usr/local/path/to/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar
```

Environment variables (spark_env.sh):

```
HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/path/to/hadoop 
SPARK_HOME=/usr/local/path/to/spark
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/path/to/hadoop/etc/hadoop
SPARK_CONF_DIR=/usr/local/path/to/spark/conf
HADOOP_LZO_DIR=/usr/local/path/to/hadoop/lib
HADOOP_CLASSPATH=$HADOOP_CLASSPATH:/usr/local/path/to/spark/*:/usr/local/path/to/spark/lib/*:/usr/local/path/to/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/local/path/to/hadoop/lib/native/*
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/local/path/to/hadoop/lib/native
SPARK_CLASSPATH=$SPARK_CLASSPATH:/usr/local/path/to/hadoop/lib/native/*:/usr/local/path/to/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar:/usr.local/path/to/spark/lib/*:$CLASSPATH
```

I purposefully added `/usr/local/path/to/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar` in SPARK_CLASSPATH to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Next steps helped me to solve similar problem:

Download hadoop library from https://hadoop.apache.org/releases.html, 
unpack it locally and set `spark.driver.extraLibraryPath` to `$HADOOP_PATH/lib/native`.

Example:

`pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.11:1.5.0 --master "local[8]" --conf "spark.driver.extraLibraryPath=/home/hadoop/hadoop-2.8.1/lib/native" --driver-memory 6G --executor-memory 6G --jars /usr/local/path/to/hadoop/lib/snappy-java-1.0.4.1.jar`

You can try to set `spark.executor.extraLibraryPath` to the same value if it doesn't work for you.